# Inheritance and extension of XML (menu) resources

Tags: android, android-menu

Is it possible to inherit and extend XML resources in android easily, specifically for menus.

For example. if my base_menu.xml is

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/item_manual_input"
        android:title="@string/manual_input/">

    <item android:id="@+id/item_logoff"
        android:title="@string/logoff"/>

</menu>
```

Both options I'd like to reuse elsewhere (in another activity). instead of repeating the  tags for the items in base_menu, I'd very much like to do something like this for inheriting_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <menu android:id="@id/base_menu"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/extra_option"
        android:title="@string/extra_option/>

</menu>
```

but I don't see anything similar to this in any documentation. Is anything like this supported, or am I stuck with using fragments to limit code and XML replication for various XML resources? (I believe this would work, but I haven't used fragments yet)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not possible for *menus* but doable for *layouts*.
See `include` tag: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

For the menu:
You can work around in the code by inflating menu xml files and adding single menu items:

```
@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.base, menu); // All menus in base.xml
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.extras, menu); // base.xml + extras.xml
    menu.add("More"); // base.xml + extras.xml + "More"
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Includes are a very powerful tool, and probably underused by a number of android developers. The programmatic workaround works for one additional layer, but beyond that, we're still stuck. fully-featured inheritance, like class inheritance, would be wonderful, but I imagine many apps don't really use it. There just aren't any good options I've seen that don't violate one OOP principle or another

Comment: The link above is dead but I found it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html). There is another similarly interesting article by Romain Guy here: [http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html). Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Whoa, I had no clue you could run inflate more than once, with different menus, thanks for sharing this